# Ubuntu 20.04 goes blank after unlocking

Tags: laptop, screen, hp, 20.04, gpu

So every time i unlock my laptop this happens :
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/gf8r4n/ubuntu_2004_goes_blank_after_unlocking/

Comment: To me it seems like a hardware issue. Is this only happening with your Ubuntu installation (in case it's a dual boot)?

Comment: On windows is normal (dual boot)

Answer (score 0):

It was extension problem.
This extension caused problem: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/